# EF Core : Database First Conversion : Foreign Key wrong column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, foreign-keys, ef-core-2.2

I am trying to embrace asp.net core by migrating my existing application from .net 4.6.2 with EF6 to .net Core 2.2 with EF Core.

Given that I have an existing database I generated the model from the database to move start with. All of my column names use underscores and where foreign keys live they all start with the table name.

With EF Core it insists that my code column names change from Manager_UserLogin_ID to ManagerUserLoginId which is fine and I can go through my code

The problem arises when I try and query the UserLogin and Manager using the include

```
__DB.UserLogin.Include(x=>x.Manager).First();
```

The query trying to run tries to include a UserLoginId column in the Manager query as well as the Manager_UserLogin_ID column.

The Classes are as follows

```
public partial class Manager
{
    public int ManagerId { get; set; }
    public int ManagerCompanyId { get; set; }
    public int ManagerUserLoginId { get; set; }
    public virtual Company ManagerCompany { get; set; }
    public virtual UserLogin ManagerUserLogin { get; set; }
}

public partial class UserLogin
{
    public UserLogin()
    {
        Manager = new HashSet<Manager>();
    }

    public int UserLoginId { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Manager> Manager { get; set; }
}

public partial class Company
{
    public Company()
    {
        Manager = new HashSet<Manager>();
    }

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Manager> Manager { get; set; }
}
```

The EF Core context has the following

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Company>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(e => e.CompanyId).HasName("PK_Company_ID");
        entity.Property(e => e.CompanyId).HasColumnName("Company_ID");

        entity.Property(e => e.CompanyName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnName("Company_Name")
            .HasMaxLength(200);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Manager>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(e => e.ManagerId)
            .HasName("PK_Manager_ID")
            .ForSqlServerIsClustered(false);

        entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.ManagerCompanyId, e.ManagerUserLoginId })
            .HasName("IX_Manager")
            .IsUnique()
            .ForSqlServerIsClustered();

        entity.Property(e => e.ManagerId).HasColumnName("Manager_ID");

        entity.Property(e => e.ManagerCompanyId).HasColumnName("Manager_Company_ID");

        entity.Property(e => e.ManagerUserLoginId).HasColumnName("Manager_UserLogin_ID");

        entity.HasOne(d => d.ManagerCompany)
            .WithMany(p => p.Manager)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.ManagerCompanyId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_Manager_Company_ID");

        entity.HasOne(d => d.ManagerUserLogin)
            .WithMany(p => p.Manager)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.ManagerUserLoginId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_Manager_UserLogin_ID");
        });

    modelBuilder.Entity<UserLogin>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(e => e.UserLoginId).HasName("PK_UserLogin_ID");
        entity.HasIndex(e => e.UserLoginUid)
            .HasName("IX_UserLogin_UID")
            .IsUnique();

        entity.Property(e => e.UserLoginId).HasColumnName("UserLogin_ID");

        entity.Property(e => e.FullName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnName("Full_Name")
            .HasMaxLength(300);

        entity.Property(e => e.UserLoginUid).HasColumnName("UserLogin_UID");
    });
```

And here is the query from Sql Profiler

```
    exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [x.Manager].[Manager_ID], [x.Manager].[Manager_Company_ID], [x.Manager].[Manager_UserLogin_ID], , [x.Manager].[UserLoginId]
    FROM [Manager] AS [x.Manager]
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT TOP(1) [x0].[UserLogin_ID]
        FROM [UserLogin] AS [x0]
        WHERE [x0].[UserLogin_UID] = @____UID_0
        ORDER BY [x0].[UserLogin_ID]
    ) AS [t] ON [x.Manager].[Manager_UserLogin_ID] = [t].[UserLogin_ID]
    ORDER BY [t].[UserLogin_ID]',N'@____UID_0 uniqueidentifier',@____UID_0='F55C9BBB-C7FF-4C87-B834-B2FE6B0F0B17'
```

Please can someone help my diagnose and fix this issue?

Comment: This could help you https://andrewlock.net/customising-asp-net-core-identity-ef-core-naming-conventions-for-postgresql/

Comment: Thanks for the article but it doesn't answer the question of why my code is creating a query containing a rouge column at the end.

I used the user and manager tables as an example I an referring to my entire database and all of its queries

Comment: Can you show me your manager and user class? Btw I never tried codeFirst with existing DB but codeFirst is actually fine with FK like User_Id

Comment: The code was generated by the VS command line. I've added the User, Company and Manager classes

Comment: Is that the whole configuration? E.g. Manager configuration (modelBuilder) has ManagerUserLoginId but doesn´t have that property in the class..?

Comment: Im trying to post a example modifying the actual code. My User table is actually UserLogin.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve tried a few things yesterday and I was fine with changing the propertyNames:

Change `public int ManagerUserLoginId { get; set; }` to `public int Manager_UserLogin_Id { get; set; }` and remove `entity.Property(e => e.Manager_UserLogin_Id).HasColumnName("Manager_UserLogin_ID");` from your modelBuilder.

That is a quickFix.. The problem behind that seems to be a bigger problem. I would create a new Database with the same configuration/classes VS created for you.

- Create a new Project
- Add a connection string with a new DB-Name
- Paste in your classes
- Create a new DbContext
- Go to package manager console and paste in `add-migration InitialMigration`

Ef Core will create a migration to create a new database, based on your model an configuration.
**Attention**: Be sure that your connectionString does not point to any existing Database. If you execute the migration, you´ll lose the data in any existing database!

- If you are **absolutely sure** that you point to a new DB paste in `update-database`

After that you can insert new Data to your TestDB to check where the problem is.

Comment: Would you like my actual code instead of the one I made a mistake on?

Comment: I don´t understand your question.. To give you the answer you need, I need the complete code causing problems...? Are User and UserLogin two different entities?

Comment: I have updated the question with the code from the solution instead of the one I tried to use as an example

Comment: Stephen, thats far too much information! You should only post the things that are relevant to your question! I don´t have enough reputation to edit your answer - I´ll post a version which you can take as another answer. Please take the examples from this answer for your question

Comment: I added the HasKey elements to the model as they were not created by the tool but the query remains the same

Comment: To avoid misunderstandings: HasKey is not part of the model! Its part of your DB-Configuration. The code you´ve showed me only contains a key-configuration for Manager-Entity..

Comment: It seems such a shame to have to ditch so much hard work and start a new project. It is a shame that Microsofts EF Core is not more accommodating

Comment: Its always hard to find a one-for-all solution. EF depends heavily on conventions - I think that is the problem.. I´ve made an edit to my answer - that should quickfix your problems. For the root problem you can also file an github-issue for EF Core